# How to run ABAQUS noGUI mdb.openStep function?

Tags: abaqus, step

I have a python script `myscript.py` where i read a step file into a new modeldatabase, with the following Code:

```
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
backwardCompatibility.setValues(includeDeprecated=True, reportDeprecated=False)

mdb.Model("Model-1")
stepFile = r"C:\...\file.step"

step = mdb.openStep(stepFile, scaleFromFile=OFF)
Part = mdb.Model["Model-1"].PartFromGeometryFile(combine=False, dimensionality=THREE_D, geometryFile=step,
                                                 name="Part-1", type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)
...
```

If i run this script in the command line with `abaqus cae noGUI=myscript.py` i get the error message `'Mdb' object has no attribute 'openStep'`

Why is this script not working with noGUI?

If i run the script with `abaqus cae script=myscript.py` everything runs fine.

Since my automation is a parameter study with a lot of cases i need to get the runtime down -> noGUI.

Comment: Not sure why, but your observation is correct. You can raise this issue in Simulia Forum. [here](https://r1132100503382-eu1-3dswym.3dexperience.3ds.com/?_gl=1*174m7cj*_ga*MTg2NTA4ODc4MC4xNzAwNzE1Njc2*_ga_DYJDKXYEZ4*MTcwMDgwMzcyMC4zLjEuMTcwMDgwMzc4NS41OS4wLjA.&serverId=SwymHttpdTomcatServer_4_8081#home) This is the official Forum; you need to create an account and ask question.